# Express.js - Execute function on every HTTP request

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

I have a function `unzip()` on my local Node.js server that downloads a `.json.gz` file from an [AWS CloudFront URL](http://post.s3post.cf/s3posts.json.gz) and unzips it to `.json`, when the server is run with `node app.js`.

The posts from that json file are loaded before responding to routes -

```
app.all('*', function(req, res, next){
    fs.readFile('s3posts.json', function(err, data){
        res.locals.posts = JSON.parse(data);
        next();
    });
});
```

The problem is that the file is downloaded and unzipped when the server starts running, and serves that same data to the user as long as it's running. The file is not re-downloaded unless the server is restarted. So, any changes to that data is not reflected until the restart.

I've tried calling the `unzip()` function inside of the above mentioned `app.all()` route before the `fs.readFile()` function that reads from the json file, but that throws an error when I request any page -

```
undefined:1
undefined
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at ReadFileContext.callback (/Users/Anish/Workspace/NodeJS/unzipper/app.js:48:27)
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:359:13)
```

When I look in the directory, I see that it downloaded the file but failed to unzip it. Even the downloaded file is corrupt and can't be unzipped manually.

*NOTE - The file downloads, unzips and gets served fine if it's placed outside of `app.all()`.*

How can I download and unzip the file on every request from the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to use the [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) module to do this -

```
app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
    request({
        method: 'GET',
        uri: 'http://post.s3post.cf/s3posts.json.gz',
        gzip: true
    }, function(error, response, body) {
        res.locals.posts = JSON.parse(body);
        next();
    });
});
```

This also eliminated the need for me to have a custom `unzip()` function that downloaded and unzipped the file.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend reading about middlewares in https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html

app.use(function(request)... should help you deal with all request regardless of the routing.

Comment: Based on your suggestion, I tried using -

`app.use(function(req) {
 unzip();
});`

@eavichay The file is downloaded and unzipped successfully, but my pages aren't being served. The browser just keeps waiting. I tried using the `next` parameter and placed the `next()` function after `unzip()` but I'm getting the error - `TypeError: next is not a function`. Any idea why?

Comment: you should call next() callback. The middlewares do exactly what you want, and pass on the request. The function get a request, response and next callback arguments, and you should use the next if you want the server to go on with the request, or use next(false) if you want to drop it.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this,

```
app.all('*', function(req, res, next){
    fs.readFile('http://post.s3post.cf/s3posts.json.gz', function(err, data){
        res.locals.posts = JSON.parse(data);
        next();
    });
});
```